# Displaying multiple WayPoints on Google Map v3

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3

The map doesn't display direction render when multiple WayPoint is pushed.  The waypoints are generated array-wise. Every index of the array is an stopover. Can someone tell me where am i wrong please. Here is part of my code

```
    var map;

    var data = new Array();

    var minZoomLevel =9;

    function load(){

        map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map_container'), 

       {
        'zoom':minZoomLevel, 

        'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 

        'center': new google.maps.LatLng(-20.131758, 57.587188),

        'mapTypeControlOptions': 
 {style:google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}

     })


//getDijstra's shortest path

downloadUrl("dijkstraAlgorithm.php", function(data) {

    var xml = data.responseXML;

    var city = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("city");

    var len = city.length;

    var latLng = [];

    //loop into cities

    for (var i =0; i <len;i++){

         var  address = city[i].getAttribute("address");

         latLng.push(address);

 }

    displayOptimisedPath(latLng);
```

});

function displayOptimisedPath (ray){

```
//build the waypoints

//free api allows a max of 9 total stops including the start and end address

//premier allows a total of 25 stops.

var items = ray;

//alert(items);

var waypoints = [];

len = items.length-1;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    var address = items[i];

    if (address !== "") {

        waypoints.push({

            location: address,

            stopover: true

        });
    }
```

}

```
var originAddress = items[0];

var destinationAddress = items[len];

//build directions request

directionService();

var request = {

        origin: originAddress,

        destination: destinationAddress,

        waypoints: waypoints,

        optimizeWaypoints: true, //set to true if you want google to determine the shortest route or false to use the order specified.

        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING

    };

//get the route from the directions service

directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

        directionDisplay.setDirections(response);

    }

    else {

    }

});
```

}//end function

function directionService(){

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

var renderOptions = { draggable: false };

var directionDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(renderOptions);

//set the directions display service to the map

directionDisplay.setMap(map);

//set the directions display panel

//panel is usually just and empty div.  

//This is where the turn by turn directions appear.

directionDisplay.setPanel(directionsPanel);

}
```

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {

```
 var request = window.ActiveXObject ?

     new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'):

     new XMLHttpRequest;

 request.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (request.readyState == 4) {

      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;

      callback(request, request.status);

    }

  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);

  request.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The call of `directionService()` doesn't make the instances of  `google.maps.DirectionsService` and `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer` accessible inside `displayOptimisedPath()` , they are only available in `directionService()` .

simplified issue:

```
function b()
{
  var c='I am C';
}

function a()
{
  b();
  alert(typeof c);//will be undefined
}
a();
```